# Matplotlib Bar Graph Yaxis not being set to 0

Tags: matplotlib

Alrighty guys I am having trouble with changing my range for the y axis values. So the problem right now is that the min is set to the lowest number in my data and the maximum is the largest number in my data.

Here is my code:

```
n_heros = np.arange(len(naHeroNameList))
pick_rate = naPickRateList
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10), dpi= 80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.bar(n_heros, pick_rate)
plt.xticks(n_heros, naHeroNameList)
plt.xlabel('Hero Name')
plt.ylabel('Pick Rate %')
plt.title('North American Contenders Season 1')
plt.show()
```

naHeroNameList is simply a list of ten names and naPickRateList is a list of numbers from 0-100 which shows the percentage of the amount of times this name is selected.

This code is outputting this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2mG5.jpg

I understand I can do plt.ylim(0,100) but that is screwing everything up for

some reason and outputting this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spsda.jpg

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you provide some data which reproduces this issue for you?

Comment: Apparently `naPickRateList` is a list of strings and you forgot to convert it to numbers before plotting.